# Check a PDF is a portfolio or not using Powershell and iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, pdf, itext

I want to cycle through PDF's and check for portfolios using powershell and iTextSharp but am not familiar with this can any one help me.

This is my sample Code:

```
$pdfFile = C:\temp\portfolio.pdf
Add-Type -Path  "C:\temp\itextsharp.dll"
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader $pdfFile
$cat = $readerp.Catalog
$pdfnames = $cat.GetAsDict(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.COLLECTION)
If $pdfnames -ne $null
{ Do Something }
```

Comment: Can you further define a "portfolio"? What does it constitute, and how would you go about (manually) determining whether a PDF is a portfolio or not?

Comment: A *portfolio* is Adobe's term for what the PDF specification calls a *portable collection*.